# How to set content for links from a nested navigation

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am confused... Actually I don't know if this is really a problem with ASP.NET.

I want to use a **nested** navigation thing (navbar or sidebar or tags or ...) for some subpages. 
For better understanding: What I want to achieve is similar to the familiar [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) structure. On the left side there is the main menu (always visible). On the top there is a submenu (for editing, version history, ...). But I need such a submenu **just for one main menu item**. My main menu is nested in the header of the page, so it is always visible. Now I declare a submenu on any other page. When I click on a link of my submenu, the new page is loaded, and replaces the whole content (including my submenu).

So what I could need is something like a sub header for a specific page.

What I need is a hint for the approach or a library (or maybe just a key word) how to create a nested navigation bar.

Comment: Post your code, clarify your specific problem. It is impossible to know what you're talking about from this paragraph.

Comment: may be he's saying about ajax page loading

Comment: ok, I changed my post. Hopefully it is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. I need to declare nested layout pages. A pretty straight forward solution is described here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/164/Nested-Layout-Pages-with-Razor